# How to save multiple data on mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Current code can save single data. I have multiple data at incoming request. How can i save the multiple data to mongodb? As you can see in the image there are 3 different objects.

[image: data]

**Orders route**

```js
router.route("/api/orders").post((req, res) => {
  const body = req.body;
  console.log(body);

  const orderid = req.body.id;
  const ordername = req.bodyname;
  const orderdescription = req.bodydescription;
  const orderquantity = req.bodyquantity;
  const ordertotalprice = req.bodytotalPrice;
  const newOrder = new Orders({
    orderid,
    ordername,
    orderdescription,
    orderquantity,
    ordertotalprice
  });

  newOrder
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Order Added!");
      res.status(200).json("Order Added!");
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request body is an array of objects.

You can use [Model.insertMany()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany) method to insert multiple documents.
Before using insertMany be sure, you convert the objects in request body to the mongoose model object correctly. Here I used javascript map method to show a sample, you may need to change that transformation.

```js
router.route("/api/orders").post((req, res) => {
  const body = req.body;
  console.log(body);

  let items = req.body.map(item => {
    return {
      orderid: item.id,
      ordername: item.name,
      orderdescription: item.description,
      orderquantity: item.quantity,
      ordertotalprice: item.totalPrice
    };
  });

  Orders.insertMany(items)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Orders Added!");
      res.status(200).json("Order Added!");
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Now i saw my mistake. I used a map too. I made a mistake there. Thank you very much @SuleymanSah its working perfect.